# Vue - How to access to $refs on rendering?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a template similar to this in my app:

```
<div style="position: relative">
  <!-- reference element -->
  <img src="imgSrc" alt="" width="500px" height="350px"
    style="border: 1px solid gray; border-radius: 10px"
    ref="image">
    
  <div v-for="(item, idx) in 5" :key="idx"
    style="position: absolute;">

    <!-- elements I want to render -->
    <div style="border: 2px solid gray"
      :style="getBoxSize(idx)"></div>
  </div>
    
  <input type="checkbox">
</div>
```

Method:

```
getBoxSize(idx) {
  if (this.$refs.image) {
    return {
      top: 50 * idx + 'px',
      left: '50px',
      width: this.$refs.image.width, // use ref's property for style
      height: '50px'
    }
  }
}
```

The problem here is that those elements I want to render will not show up until I click an input or do something that change the UI. When I log `this.$refs.image`, it returned `undefined` at first, and then it returned the referenced element after I triggered some UI changes.

I could avoid the problem by deferring a few miliseconds and actively trigger some changes on `mount()`, but that's not how I want things to go. I guess the `$refs` is not available on rendering (?)

Is there anyway to catch the `$refs` element and use its properties to render other elements on rendering?

Comment: making it a computed property won't work ?

Comment: still, I don't get it. Since getBoxSize is called only when the elements show up, the $refs.image should have the correct value when it's called

Comment: @vicovicovico since this method takes some input arguments which are generated on rendering, I don't think it's suited for computed property

Comment: @vicovicovico that's what I thought, and yet it still showed `undefined` when I logged it

Comment: [Docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements) - *`$refs` are only populated after the component has been rendered, and they are not reactive. It is only meant as an escape hatch for direct child manipulation - you should avoid accessing `$refs` from within templates or computed properties.*